# Design a multi file type config loader class with Inversion of Control

Tags: php, dependency-injection

Let's say I have a class that loads and parses a config file. However that config file can be of 3 types:

- JSON
- YAML
- INI

How can I design my "configLoader" in order to keep things:

1. loosely coupled
2. easy to unit test
3. easy to switch components (change an old parser for a new better one, for instance)

but at the same time:

1. Easy to extend (and by that I mean adding new types of accepted files like XML, for instance)
2. Without extensive constructors or setters in order for the class to work

---

### Some notes

- All parsers implement the same interface (ParserInterface)
- Can act as wrappers (Adapters) for well known parsers such as Symfony/Yaml, for instance
- This class is initialized prior to DI Container initialization (along in the logic, the values loaded here will actually be injected in the DI container) so using it here is not an  option

---

## Code

Here's what I have so far:

```
class Loader
{

    /**
     * Loads a configuration string from a ConfigFile
     * 
     * @param ConfigFile $configFile
     * @throws ConfigException if the file type is not recognised
     * @return Config ArrayObject with configuration settings
     */
    public function loadFromFile(ConfigFile $configFile)
    {
        // Finds out what type of config file it is
        $type = $configFile->getType();
        //Loads the file into memory
        $configString = $configFile->read();
        
        switch ($type) {
            case ConfigFile::TYPE_YAML:
                $parser = new YAML\YamlParser(); //Here's the problem
                break;
            
            case ConfigFile::TYPE_JSON:
                $parser = new JSON\JsonParser(); //Here's the problem
                break;
            // (...) same for other file types
            
            // Default case if file type is not recognised
            default:
                throw new ConfigException('Config File type not recognised');
        }
        return $parser->decode($configString);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: This class is difficult to test because it initializes the instance of the parser locally. Also, If someone wants to add new types of files, the loadfromfile method will have to be overloaded (althougt the only thing needed to change would be the switch case, where he would only had to add a new cse for the specific file type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
interface ParserInterface{
  public static test(ConfigFile $configFile);
  // other required methods
}
```

Your loader method:

```
$classes = get_declared_classes();
foreach($classes as $class){
  $class = new \ReflectionClass($class);

  if(!$class->implementsInterface('ParserInterface'))
    continue;

  $parser = $class->getName();

  if(!$parser::test($configFile))
    continue;

  $parser = $class->newInstance();
  return $parser->decode(...);
}  

throw new Exception(...);
```

And you've just "inversed the control" to the point that the config file itself determines what parser gets to be used

Answer (score 1):

I would do it **a lot** like the [Symfony Config Component](https://github.com/symfony/Config). Actually, I'd probably just use it.

Comment: The symfony config loader is very good, but has a lot of features I don't need and can become slow. I was actually using it but was asked to redesign this part